# Easiest Way to AutoRefresh Google Charts embeded within a page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-visualization

I have two files, one outputting data from a MySQL database and one drawing a Google Graph within a page with other metrics:

grab_twitter_stats.php Output:

```
[15, 32], [14, 55], [13, 45], [12, 52], [11, 57], [10, 55], [9, 58], [8, 42], [7, 44], [6, 40], [5, 54], [4, 52], [3, 60], [2, 71], [1, 43],
```

index.php Output:

```
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px">

<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Minutes', 'Tweets'],

      <?php require('grab_twitter_stats.php');?>

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Tweets in last 15 Minutes',
      curveType: 'function',
      hAxis: {
      title: 'Last 15 Minutes',
      direction: '-1'
      },
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

}

</script>   
</div>
```

This draws a graph that shows tweets in the last 15 minutes.  I can get the graph to appear once, but upon trying to load a SetInterval, it does not refresh the Google Graph on the interval.  I have tried wrapping the entire drawChart() function in it, and it doesn't seem to be working.  I tried using AJAX but it is not formatted in JSON so ajax doesn't like it.  Any suggestions on the easiest way to make this graph auto refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although not JSON, you can still use ajax, even with plain text

something like this should get you close...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, (15 * 60 * 1000));

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'grab_twitter_stats.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (txt) {
          // check for trailing comma
          if (txt.slice(-1) === ',') {
            txt = txt.substring(0, txt.length - 1);
          }
          var txtData = JSON.parse('[["Minutes", "Tweets"],' + txt + ']');

          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(txtData);

          var options = {
            title: 'Tweets in last 15 Minutes',
            curveType: 'function',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Last 15 Minutes',
              direction: '-1'
            },
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Hi White Hat.  Close but I got the following error: VM852:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 174

Comment: are you removing the trailing comma as in the answer above?

Comment: Yes same error, but it moved: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 23success @ (index):77j @ jquery-latest.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery-latest.min.js:2x @ jquery-latest.min.js:4b @ jquery-latest.min.js:4

Comment: So it looks like it works when there is only one entry, but if there are multiple it stops working.  What should I use as a separator?

Comment: I found the separator.  It has to look like this:  [15, 106],[14, 105],[13, 110],[12, 119],[11, 107],[10, 132],[9, 121],[8, 111],[7, 126],[6, 115],[5, 109],